# DaoException: No DAO registered for class

Tags: android, join, greendao, greendao-generator

I am trying to perform a join with `GreenDao` on my `Android` project, this is my code:

```
QueryBuilder<User> queryBuilder = daoSession.getUserDao().queryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.join(UserDao.Properties.Id, TeamDao.class,TeamDao.Properties.UserId);
```

but I am getting this error:

```
de.greenrobot.dao.DaoException: No DAO registered for class com.test.TeamDao
```

I am not sure where the error is. I have the TeamDao class in the `Dao Generated` folder

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Dao Generated` folder there should be a `Team` class as well as the `TeamDao` class, so try:

```
QueryBuilder<User> queryBuilder = daoSession.getUserDao().queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.join(UserDao.Properties.Id, Team.class, TeamDao.Properties.UserId);
```